# Why ini file is not being saved?

Tags: delphi, unicode, settings, ini, delphi-xe5

I am trying to save unicode string. There is what I have:

```
Uses IniFiles;
const
SZ_APP_NAME;

Procedure TForm1.SaveSettings;
var
  _MemIniU: TMemIniFile;
  SettingsPath: string;
begin
  SettingsPath := GetHomePath + PathDelim + SZ_APP_NAME + PathDelim;
  _MemIniU := TMemIniFile.Create(ChangeFileExt(SettingsPath, 'Settings.ini'),
    TEncoding.UTF8);
  try
    if Form1.WindowState <> TWindowState.wsMaximized then
    begin
      _MemIniU.WriteInteger(SZ_APP_NAME, 'WindowLeft', Form1.Left);
      _MemIniU.WriteInteger(SZ_APP_NAME, 'WindowTop', Form1.Top);
      _MemIniU.WriteInteger(SZ_APP_NAME, 'WindowWidth', Form1.Width);
      _MemIniU.WriteInteger(SZ_APP_NAME, 'WindowHeight', Form1.Height);
      _MemIniU.WriteString(SZ_APP_NAME, 'UnicodeText', Edit1.Text);
    end;
  finally
    _MemIniU.Free;
  end;
end;
```

But ini file is NOT created. What I am doing wrong? RAD Studio XE5.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You have to call `TMemIniFile.UpdateFile` to save the information into the file.

Documentation is very clear to that

> **TMemIniFile** buffers all changes to the INI file. The INI file is read once, when the object is first created. Data from the INI file is stored in nested string lists. Each section in the INI file occupies one element in the top-most string list, and each element in this may itself contain a string list. Each element in each of the contained string list represents a key within the section. After the data is read, any changes to the data are stored in memory. To write the data from memory back to the associated INI file, call the **UpdateFile** method.

[DocWiki TMemIniFile](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE3/en/System.IniFiles.TMemIniFile)

Answer (score 3):

I modified your code. You can see there is "**_MemIniU.UpdateFile;**" command below.

If you don't use **UpdateFile** command, any changes you make will not be saved.

Best Regards

```
Uses IniFiles;
const
SZ_APP_NAME;

Procedure TForm1.SaveSettings;
var
  _MemIniU: TMemIniFile;
  SettingsPath: string;
begin
  SettingsPath := GetHomePath + PathDelim + SZ_APP_NAME + PathDelim;
  _MemIniU := TMemIniFile.Create(ChangeFileExt(SettingsPath, 'Settings.ini'),
    TEncoding.UTF8);
  try
    if Form1.WindowState <> TWindowState.wsMaximized then
    begin
      _MemIniU.WriteInteger(SZ_APP_NAME, 'WindowLeft', Form1.Left);
      _MemIniU.WriteInteger(SZ_APP_NAME, 'WindowTop', Form1.Top);
      _MemIniU.WriteInteger(SZ_APP_NAME, 'WindowWidth', Form1.Width);
      _MemIniU.WriteInteger(SZ_APP_NAME, 'WindowHeight', Form1.Height);
      _MemIniU.WriteString(SZ_APP_NAME, 'UnicodeText', Edit1.Text);
      _MemIniU.UpdateFile;
    end;
  finally
    _MemIniU.Free;
  end;
end;
```