# Delphi 2009: write string in UTF-8 lost characters

Tags: string, utf-8, delphi-2009

I tested code posted here:
[Why ini file is not being saved?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20674809/why-ini-file-is-not-being-saved)

After call "SaveSettings" procedure settings.ini is saved in UTF-8 format, all is OK. After second call (settings.ini already exists), ini file is updated but UTF8 encoded characters are lost, ??????????? is displayed instead. File encoding is lost ini contain plain TEXT.

```
Uses IniFiles;
const
SZ_APP_NAME;

Procedure TForm1.SaveSettings;
var
  _MemIniU: TMemIniFile;
  SettingsPath: string;
begin
  SettingsPath := GetHomePath + PathDelim + SZ_APP_NAME + PathDelim;
  _MemIniU := TMemIniFile.Create(ChangeFileExt(SettingsPath, 'Settings.ini'),
    TEncoding.UTF8);
  try
    if Form1.WindowState <> TWindowState.wsMaximized then
    begin
      _MemIniU.WriteInteger(SZ_APP_NAME, 'WindowLeft', Form1.Left);
      _MemIniU.WriteInteger(SZ_APP_NAME, 'WindowTop', Form1.Top);
      _MemIniU.WriteInteger(SZ_APP_NAME, 'WindowWidth', Form1.Width);
      _MemIniU.WriteInteger(SZ_APP_NAME, 'WindowHeight', Form1.Height);
      _MemIniU.WriteString(SZ_APP_NAME, 'UnicodeText', Edit1.Text);
      _MemIniU.UpdateFile;
    end;
  finally
    _MemIniU.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: What are you using to view the inifile afterwards and which version of Delphi are you using?

Comment: Delphi 2009, to view ini file i used notepad.exe and build-in Lister  in Total commander (F3 key)

Comment: I tried compile it in Delphi-XE5 and there is no problem..., hmm when i replace TEncoding.UTF8 with TEncoding.Unicode and compile in Delphi 2009 then there is no problem, "unicode" is defalut setting for string in Delphi 2009 right?

Comment: Right. How are the format of the your .ini file? Because exists four encodings at notepad.exe for example: ANSI, Unicode, Unicode big endian and UTF-8.

Please, change the format of the .ini file from Unicode and try again. Also post your results. Thanks.

Comment: For UTF-8 with Delphi 2009 it dosn't work => second call of procedure causes ini is saved without encoding. For "Unicode" with Delphi 2009 is not problem.

Comment: I think you should tag the question with Delphi version. Perhaps this is a defect that has been fixed in later versions.

Comment: @Nafalem: did you verify that the actual raw byte encoding of the two ini files, from the first and second saves, are identical? Did you verify that the file is actually being loaded correctly after the first save? When you say the second file is "saved without encoding", what does that mean exactly? Just that a BOM is missing? Or the actual encoding of the bytes is different?

Comment: @Remy Lebeau, in D2009 the second call saves settings.ini in ANSI format instead of UTF-8 , but only if settings.ini exists, so yes the raw data are different. UTF-8 read works correctly. Second call works only if settings.ini is enconded "Unicode" or "Unicode big endian". https://www.copy.com/s/uExSe4P09mJS/ini-UTF8-BUG.rar (contains source + compiled binaries D2009/D-XE5